# Sorting multiple fields in Ascending and Descending order in mongodb with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have some fields from mongodb that i am trying to sort in asc or desc order but the return values i get after making the queries is rather inconsistent. i have gone through the documentation and tried to tailor my approach to how it was in the documentation.

i have tried this

```
  sort({"email": -1,
    "dob": -1,
    "website": -1,
    "lastName": -1,
    "firstName": -1,})
```

And  this `sort("-firstName, -lastName , -email , -dob , -website")` for descending order but it works correctly for only one field. e.g  **lastName** and returns an inconsistent data for the rest.

**This is the exact same behavior when trying to sort by Ascending order too.**

what am i doing wrongly?

Comment: Can you provide an example and result?

Comment: I already did in the post. running the highlighted sort query only returns true for 1 field. only the lastName field gets sorted correctly

Answer (score 0):

according to mongo official documentation you need to add a field which contains exclusively unique values to the sort.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/

do not forget to add also the required indexes to avoid performances issues.

Comment: Hi. does sort({email: -1}) count as a field. if yes, i already did that. if i add multiple fields, it only resolves the first one.

Comment: in your collection, the email is unique value? can you share an example of the documents you have in your db?

Comment: firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter a valid first name."],
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter a valid last name."],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please provide a valid email address."],
    },   This is a part of my schema

Comment: i guess you are using mongoose? if thats the case i dont see you added a unique property for any of your fields. am i missing something?

Comment: Oh i need to add unique properties to each field? Let me try that right away

Comment: you need at least to have one field that we will be unique to make sure the order will be remain and it will block in the db level from inserting multiple documents the same value for those fields. it depend on your use case, are you expecting to have multiple documents with the same value or not. for example first and last name should not be unique but email is a good candidate.

Comment: in any case you can add _id as part of your sorting query (without adding unique index for on or more of you fields) and it should work for you.

Comment: Yes i am expecting to have multiple values with the same document. i have added a unique prop set to true to the email.  UserModel.find({}).sort({firstName: 'asc', lastName: 'asc'}) tried to run that query and it only resolves for the firstName. the lastName doesnt get sorted in asc order. i don't understand why it only works for the first field and ignore whichever comes after. thank you for taking out time to discuss this with me,

Comment: you should add a unique field in your query. add the _id/email(in case its unique right now) in addition and it will work for u

Comment: UserModel.find({}).sort({ email: 'asc', firstName: 'asc', lastName: 'asc'}) i've added an email field to the query and funnily it only returns the ascending value for the email field and ignores the rest. phew!